# InfoBubble does not populate with AJAX call

Tags: jquery, maps, infobubble

I have interesting problem. I am using infoBubble and JQuery to show info when user clicks on marker on google maps V3.
It works if I use infoBubble.addTab('tab info', data); but not if I use infoBubble.setContent(content);

Example code:

```
// some code here

infoBubble = new InfoBubble({
   maxWidth:  480,
   maxHeight: 250,
   borderRadius: 5,
   arrowSize: 15,
   borderWidth: 3,
   arrowPosition: 50,
   borderColor: '#D6D6D6'          
 });

$.post("/some/map/info", {id: this.get('id')}, function(data) {
          // alert (data);
          //infoBubble.addTab('Tab info', data);
          infoBubble.setContent(data);
  }); 
infoBubble.open(map, this);

// rest of the code
```

This code opens the info window, but it not populates it with the content. If I uncomment the alert box, code works! Not sure why. Also if I use addTab function it works fine. I have used FireBug to debug, all vars and data are populated correctly, and while in debug mode - it works! Soon as I am out of debug and no alert, it does not work, shows empty bubble. If anybody can shade some light, greatly appreciated.

Thanks
Alex

Comment: As the request is asynchronous, you're opening the infoBubble before the content is set.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but I just ran into the same issue and found the solution, so I'm posting here for anybody who might come across this question.

Simply move infoBubble.open inside the $.post() function

```
$.post("/some/map/info", {id: this.get('id')}, function(data) {
      infoBubble.setContent(data);
      infoBubble.open(map, this);
});
```